# Зачем у потоков есть возможность останавливать выполнение Caller-а? C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

У std::thread есть метод join(), который останавливает выполнение вызывающей функции, пока не будет выполнен поток. Но зачем это нужно? Ведь суть потока в выполнении вещей параллельно с вызывающей функцией, разве нет? Разве вместо join не проще просто написать код без потока, ведь эффект будет одинаковый?

Comment: Для *синхронизации*. Например, параллельный расчет N потоками какого-то произведения матрицы. Как точно знать, когда все потоки выполнят свою работу и можно работать дальше?... Вы хотите сказать, что такой параллельный расчет с N `join()` будет такой же по времени, как и без многопоточности?